# Threads synchronisation over C sockets

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, synchronization

I am having a problem figuring out this.

I have two threads, one executing as it follows ( T1a, T1b, T1c )
The second ( T2a, T2b, T2c )

Assuming T1a should start before T2a, and T1 and T2 are on two distant machines and network communication is needed ( TCP sockets ).

How can I establish synchronisation between these two threads ( let's say each one a function T1() and T2() ), and a consecutive execution is mundane, T1a < T2a < T1b < T2b < T1c < T2c

Comment: I'm pretty sure processes running on remote machines don't count as multithreading in any reasonable classification.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a trick question? Looks like a specific case of the basic command loop you find in a gazillion daemons since the 70s.

You just have to have each subtask send a message (through your UDP socket or any other means of communication) to the remote machine to let the next tasks begin.

Each "function" (Txy) will have a structure like

```
wait for a message signalling previous task completion
do my job
send another message to signal task completion
```

You don't actually need to write 3 functions. A single function analyzing the messages and taking the appropriate actions would be easier to maintain and more robust:

```
forever
   wait for a command
   execute the corresponding action
   possibly send a new message to trigger an action on peer side
```

You would better add a timeout for message reception to prevent the system from getting stuck if one of the computer crashes or the connexion goes down.
It would also be wise to keep track of the next expected command to make sure the actions are performed in the intended order: what would happen if one of the synchronization messages got lost?

However, I don't see the point in synchronizing tasks that would have no dependencies from each other.

Usually you only need to do that when a given task requires inputs from the previous one. For instance, grab some data from the Internet and pass it to some other computer to process.

In other words, the messages would usually contains some data necessary to perform the next part of the processing.

Comment: It's a university exercice I am trying to solve, it's mentioning that two tasks T1 and T2 should be synchronised, can be executed at the same time, but witha given that start(T2a) >= end(T1a) and start(T1c) >= end(T2b) . I still don't get how can this be synchronised over sockets, should I use mutex/semaphores for this purpose ? or a simple signalling by message can do the job

Comment: Well yes. One of the computer will assume the role of master and send commands to the other: send start message, do your T1a thing, wait for T1b to signal completion, ready to process next segment. On the slave side: wait for master order, do your T2a thing, signal end of job. Rinse and repeat. Neglecting the message tramsmission time, T1a and T2a will execute concurrently. The next step will start as soon as both are complete. And so on.